# Assemblies in v2.0 directory which using runtime 4.0

Tags: .net, dll, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

My solution is restricted  on .Net 3.5.1 and I need to use the Microsoft.Teamfoundation API which is installed with the VS 2013. The references are stored in the Mircosoft Visual Studio 12,0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0 directory, so I would think the dll's i will find in this dir are build with .Net 2.0 (which I'm able to use with .Net 3.5.1).

BUT when I import these References in VS 2013 and check the runtime version there stand that these dll's using the runtime 4.0.30319. I checked the path of the dll's and everything is correct except of the expected runtime version.

My question is: Are there dll's for the Teamfoundation API for .Net 3.5.1 (or lower) and if yes, where do I find them?
Can a lower version of VS be the solution? (i would doubt, but I'm open for suggestions)

Comment: I see it.  They goofed, you can't use them.  Try posting at connect.microsoft.com to get advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (not really a solution from my point of view, because MS should fix this, but OK)

Either you use VS 2012 instead of VS 2013 or you install the Team Explorer for VS 2012 in addition to your VS 2013. This will deliver the assemblies which are using the runtime 2.0.
Or you install the VS 2012 parallel to your 2013. Would work too, but needs more space.